# Gulp copying empty directories

Tags: node.js, glob, gulp, gulp-glob

In my *gulp* build I've made a task that runs *after* all compiling, uglifying and minification has occurred. This task simply copies everything from the *src* into the *dest* directory that hasn't been touched/processed by earlier tasks. The little issue I'm having is that this results in empty directories in the *dest* directory.

Is there a way to tell the `gulp.src` glob to only include files in the pattern matching (like providing the `'is_file'` flag)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a filter to the pipeline:

```
var es = require('event-stream');


var onlyDirs = function(es) {
  return es.map(function(file, cb) {
      if (file.stat.isFile()) {
        return cb(null, file);
      } else {
        return cb();
      }
  });
};
// ...

var s = gulp.src(globs)
        .pipe(onlyDirs(es))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folders.dest + '/' + module.folder));

// ...
```

Comment: Where did folders.dest + '/' + module.folder come from? Where are the vars for them?

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to the party on this one, but for anyone else stumbling upon this question, there is another way to do this that seems pretty elegant in my eyes. I found it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654317/gulp-glob-to-ignore-file-types-and-not-copy-empty-folders#answer-36373281)

To exclude the empty folders I added  `{ nodir: true }` after the glob pattern.

Your general pattern could be such (using the variables from [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719731/gulp-copying-empty-directories#answer-23720239)):

```
gulp.src(globs, { nodir: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folders.dest + '/' + module.folder));
```

Mine was as follows:

```
gulp.src(['src/**/*', '!src/scss/**/*.scss', '!src/js/**/*.js'], { nodir: true })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/'));
```

This selects all the files from the *src* directory that are **not** scss or js files, and does not copy any empty folders from those two directories either.

Comment: saved the day 14082017

Comment: saved the night 131018