# Gulp glob to ignore file types and not copy empty folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, glob

I have created a glob for gulp which ignores javascript and coffeescript files within a set of directories. I'd like it to copy all other files into a directory which works fine. The only problem is that when there are only javascript or coffeescript files it copies an empty folder. Any ideas how this glob could be amended to not copy empty folders?

```
gulp.task('copyfiles', function(){
    gulp.src('apps/*/static_src/**/!(*.js|*.coffee)')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Example source files:

```
apps/appname/static_src/images/image.jpg
apps/appname/static_src/js/script.js
```

Expected output:

```
dest/static_src/images/image.jpg
```

Current output:

```
dest/static_src/images/image.jpg
dest/static_src/js/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp copying empty directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719731/gulp-copying-empty-directories)

Answer (score 9):

Since `gulp.src` accepts [almost the same options as node-glob](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#options), you can add `nodir: true`as an option:

```
gulp.src('apps/*/static_src/**/!(*.js|*.coffee)', { nodir: true })
```

This will preserve the dir structure from src, but omit empty ones.

Comment: mmm - i get 'Error: Missing positive glob'  trying [globs.images,'!(*.ai|*.ai)'] or globs.images+'!(*.ai|*.ai)'

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('copyfiles', function(){
    gulp.src(['apps/*/static_src/**/*','!apps/*/static_src/{js/, js/**}'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

I think you need a pattern `'!apps/*/static_src/{js/, js/**}'` that matches the directory as well as the files inside to prevent ommiting an empty directory. I am not sure if there is a pattern to match a directory only by specifying its content.